# Using PagedList.MVC with Bootstrap modal Partials issue

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Teaching myself MVC and so the first project I wanted to complete was a simple CRUD application that used Bootstraps modal forms.

I've tried to make my requirements for this Learning project as RealWorld as possible...therefore

- Search with paging (ideally autocomplete, as in not needing a Submit button)
- Maintain current Search parameters
- CRUD with Modal Forms
- Potentially loaded via AJAX?

I have essentially fused the 2 below projects into a working application.

- [Sorting, Filtering, and Paging with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)
- [Crud operation in ASP.NET MVC using Ajax](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/1590/crud-operation-in-asp-dot-net-mvc-using-ajax)

I have a few issues with the app...firstly, in my HttpPostActionResult, if I return PartialView("_DetailPaged"), the _DetailPage partial tells me the model is null.  Because the _detailPage is looking for a model of PagedList.IPagedList, I'd theorectially have to rerun the code from the Index action.

So, I instead tried to return RedirectToAction("Index"), which works, as far as the model is able to load properly, however, becuase I'm reloading my view, some pieces of the UI become repeated.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to Load the search via ajax and only update the Details partial.
I'd like to allow the user to search the table without using the submit button, hence the above requirement and lastly, i'd like to be able to return a query with search parameters, even after an Edit or Add.

As a bonus, I want to clean up the Search query to only return a subset of data, ie these 10 records, with sme kind of bookmark as to how to query the Next or previous 10.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**My View**

```
<div id="main-div">
<div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="container">

    <a href="@Url.Action("Add", "MVCPager2")" id="Add" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>&nbsp;Create New</a>
    <div id="div-record">
        @Html.Partial("_DetailPaged", Model)      
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="Add-Model" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">New Student</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="divForAdd">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="modal fade" id="Edit-Model" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Update Student</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="divForUpdate">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Partial View**

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Employee>
@using PagedList.Mvc;

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "MVCPager", FormMethod.Get))

        {
            <p>
                Find by name: @Html.TextBox("SearchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)

                <input type="submit" value="Search" />
            </p>
        }
<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LastName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Home", new { ID = item.EmployeeID })" class="editDialog"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i>&nbsp;Edit</a>
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Ajax.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", "Home", new { @ID = item.EmployeeID }, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "div-record" }, new { @class = "fa fa-trash-o" })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber) of @Model.PageCount

@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index",
new { page, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter }))

</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Add').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get(this.href, function (response) {
            $('.divForAdd').html(response);
        });
        $('#Add-Model').modal({
            backdrop: 'static',
        }, 'show');
    });
    $('.editDialog').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get(this.href, function (response) {
            $('.divForUpdate').html(response);
        });
        $('#Edit-Model').modal({
            backdrop: 'static',
        }, 'show');
    });
});
</script>
```

**My Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string currentFilter, string searchString, int? page)
    {
        ViewBag.CurrentSort = sortOrder;
        ViewBag.NameSortParm = String.IsNullOrEmpty(sortOrder) ? "name_desc" : "";
        ViewBag.DateSortParm = sortOrder == "Date" ? "date_desc" : "Date";

        if (searchString != null)
        {
            page = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            searchString = currentFilter;
        }

        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = searchString;

        IEnumerable<Employee> Employees;
        using (NorthwindEntities ctx = new NorthwindEntities())
        {
            Employees = ctx.Employees.ToList();
        }

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
        {
            Employees = Employees.Where(s => s.LastName.Contains(searchString)
                                   || s.FirstName.Contains(searchString));
        }

        int pageSize = 10;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);            
        return View(Employees.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize));
    }

    public ActionResult Add()
    {
        return PartialView("_AddPaged");
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(Employee model)
    {
        List<Employee> Employees = new List<Employee>();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (NorthwindEntities ctx = new NorthwindEntities())
            {
                Employee _employee = new Employee
                {
                    FirstName = model.FirstName,
                    LastName = model.LastName
                };
                ctx.Employees.Add(_employee);

                try
                {
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
                {
                    // Retrieve the error messages as a list of strings.
                    var errorMessages = ex.EntityValidationErrors
                            .SelectMany(x => x.ValidationErrors)
                            .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage);

                    // Join the list to a single string.
                    var fullErrorMessage = string.Join("; ", errorMessages);

                    // Combine the original exception message with the new one.
                    var exceptionMessage = string.Concat(ex.Message, " The validation errors are: ", fullErrorMessage);

                    // Throw a new DbEntityValidationException with the improved exception message.
                    throw new DbEntityValidationException(exceptionMessage, ex.EntityValidationErrors);
                }
                Employees = ctx.Employees.ToList();
            }
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
        //return PartialView("_DetailPaged");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This JavaScript for your model popup completion.

Make a App.js in your Scripts 
and copy below code there.

**MyApp.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#add').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get(this.href, function (response) {
            $('.divForAdd').html(response);
        });
        $('#Add-Model').modal({
            backdrop: 'static',
        }, 'show');
    });


    $('.openDialog-Edit').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get(this.href, function (response) {
            $('.divForCreate').html(response);
        });

        $('#Edit-Model').modal({
            backdrop: 'static',
        }, 'show');

    });

    $('.openDialog-Delete').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.get(this.href, function (response) {
            $('.divForDelete').html(response);
        });

        $('#Delete-Model').modal({
            backdrop: 'static',
        }, 'show');

    });
});
```